# Mesh not moving with bones

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I'm trying to animate a human made in makehuman and exported to blender, parented mesh with armature with automatic weight but when i move any bone, mesh doesn't move.

This is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n2xG-fzKt1Htsx6jkmDCtSllm_UAtsYf/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It seems to have been parented With Empty Groups, which means the vertex groups have been created in the mesh but thay are not assigned to any vertex. You need to parent With Automatic Weight (Ctrl P), then you may need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode or with the Assign button under the vertex group list in the Properties panel > Object Data

Comment: Please don't use all caps in the title, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude

Comment: [Why all caps is a bad idea](https://danieltitus.com/blog/advertising/237-why-all-caps-is-usually-a-bad-idea)